# linq select many issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a person table and a colour table. each person has many colours.

```
var data = dc.People.Include(c => c.Colours)
    .Select(i => new { 
        i.PersonId, 
        FullName = i.FirstName + " " + i.LastName,
        i.IsAuthorised, 
        i.IsEnabled, 
        i.Colours
    })
    .OrderByDescending(i => i.PersonId)
    .ToList();
```

Lets just say I want to show 1, james smith, true, true, red and black.

The above code shows me an error because `i.colours` is a list.

I tried to change it to `colour = i.Colours.SelectMany(c => c.Name)`. This also gave me an error. How can I achieve my goal?

Colours is a ICollection inside my person class.
public virtual ICollection Colours { get; set; }

Here is my table diagram:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcTE0.png)

Comment: "an error because i.colours is a list.". Could you show full exception message?

Comment: You you mean you want to join the colors into one string property (you can use the `String.Join()` method

Comment: @StephenMuecke that method is not supported in Linq to Entities. It will only work if he loads all the Colors into memory first, then performs the join.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL, Yes I know :) I'm trying to understand what OP wants.

Comment: I dont understand what is the problem in the above code? why i.colours is a list is an issue here?

Comment: it would be funny if you just add a .tolist to the colors and it works ....just thinking

Comment: @StephenMuecke are you saying I should do this: String.Join(i.Colours)?

Comment: @DanNguyen I.colours is a list and it throws an error. Basically each person has a list of colours. I will post the error later on. What I really need is i.Colours.Name but I dont know how to fit it in, in the above code.

Comment: @RAHULSR I wish that would work but in the colour table I have colour.ID and colour.Name. I just need the name, which would be red, black, green.

Comment: You still have not stated what you want, but I'm guessing `var data = dc.People.Include(x => x.Colours).OrderByDescending(x => x.PersonId).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new { ID = x.PersonId, ....., Colors = String.Join("and", x.Colors) });` (assuming `Colors` is `IEnumerable<string>` - if its a complex object, then you would need another `Select()` on `x.Colors`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks ill try the code later on. I've updated my question so now it has a picture of my database. Colours is a Icollection and it has a property Name which I want. so I want something like colour.Name.

Comment: In that case - `Colors = String.Join("and", x.Colors.Select(y => y.Name))`

Comment: @StephenMuecke its working now, thanks mate. Now, this is my first time using this website, how can I pick your comment as the answer? =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there is an example with three different solutions. The main problem is there is no methods like String.Join that mapped to sql-query, so u have to

1) get all entities from DB an then use String.Join and so on

or

2) use only sql-mapped functions

I'll past it with EF entites.

Result output of code is:

> GetWithAnonymousClass:
>
> 1, james smith, True, True, red and black
>
> 2, Thomas Anderson, True, True, green and white
>
> GetByObject:
>
> 1, james smith, True, True, red and black
>
> 2, Thomas Anderson, True, True, green and white
>
> GetByString:
>
> 1, james smith, True, True, red and black
>
> 2, Thomas Anderson, True, True, green and white

Example code:

```
internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var dc = new PeopleContext("DBConnection"))
            {
                //Adding entities for example
                //AddJamesSmith(dc);
                //AddThomasAnderson(dc);

                GetWithAnonymousClass(dc);
                GetByObject(dc);
                GetByString(dc);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This example shows how to select entity with children to anonymous class
        /// plus: u can get entity with fields that u exactly need
        /// </summary>
        private static void GetWithAnonymousClass(PeopleContext dc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GetWithAnonymousClass:");
            var array = dc.People.Select(c => new {c.PersonId, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.IsAuthorised, c.IsEnabled, Colours = c.Colours.Select(cc => cc.Name)});
            foreach (var c in array)
                Console.WriteLine($"{c.PersonId}, {c.FirstName} {c.LastName}, {c.IsAuthorised}, {c.IsEnabled}, {string.Join(" and ", c.Colours)}");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This example shows how to select entity with children and use it at client (Console.WriteLine here)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dc"></param>
        private static void GetByObject(PeopleContext dc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GetByObject:");
            var array = dc.People.Include(c => c.Colours);
            foreach (var c in array)
                Console.WriteLine($"{c.PersonId}, {c.FirstName} {c.LastName}, {c.IsAuthorised}, {c.IsEnabled}, {string.Join(" and ", c.Colours.Select(cc => cc.Name))}");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        /// This example shows how to select entity with children to string formatted at Sql-server side
        /// plus: all code execuded at sql-server
        /// minus: u must specify each child explicitly. U can't is this method, if u don know number of children
        private static void GetByString(PeopleContext dc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GetByString:");
            var array = dc.People.Select(c => c.PersonId + ", " + c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName + ", " + c.IsAuthorised +
                                              ", " + c.IsEnabled + ", " + c.Colours.OrderBy(сс => сс.ColourId).FirstOrDefault().Name +
                                              " and " + c.Colours.OrderBy(сс => сс.ColourId).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().Name);

            foreach (var c in array)
                Console.WriteLine(c);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        private static void AddJamesSmith(PeopleContext dc)
        {
            dc.People.Add(
                new Person
                {
                    FirstName = "james",
                    LastName = "smith",
                    IsAuthorised = true,
                    IsEnabled = true,
                    IsValid = true,
                    Colours = new List<Colour>
                    {
                        new Colour {IsEnabled = true, Name = "red"},
                        new Colour {IsEnabled = true, Name = "black"}
                    }
                });
            dc.SaveChanges();
        }

        private static void AddThomasAnderson(PeopleContext dc)
        {
            dc.People.Add(
                new Person
                {
                    FirstName = "Thomas",
                    LastName = "Anderson",
                    IsAuthorised = true,
                    IsEnabled = true,
                    IsValid = true,
                    Colours = new List<Colour>
                    {
                        new Colour {IsEnabled = true, Name = "green"},
                        new Colour {IsEnabled = true, Name = "white"}
                    }
                });
            dc.SaveChanges();
        }
    }


    public class PeopleContext : DbContext
    {
        public PeopleContext(string connectionStringName) : base(connectionStringName)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Colour> Colours { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int PersonId { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public bool IsAuthorised { get; set; }
        public bool IsValid { get; set; }
        public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }

        public List<Colour> Colours { get; set; }
    }

    public class Colour
    {
        [Key]
        public int ColourId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }

        public List<Person> People { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
var data = dc.People
    .Select(i => new { 
        i.PersonId, 
        FullName = i.FirstName + " " + i.LastName,
        i.IsAuthorised, 
        i.IsEnabled, 
        Colours = i.Colours.ToList()
    })
    .OrderByDescending(i => i.PersonId)
    .ToList();
```

That will give you all the colours for a person as it is many-to-many

Comment: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Colour_26244490C64D3359683670B4EDCD6448410A77927B33AAF8F871FE4C04241290'.

The other answer worked though thanks

Comment: remove the `.Include(c => c.Colours)`